# Force a method to be static using type annotation/stub file

Tags: python-3.x, ide, type-hinting

For simplicity, suppose I have a metaclass which makes all the defined methods static. So

```py
class A(metaclass=AllStatic):
    def inc(x): # no need for @staticmethod
        return x + 1
```

Of course IDEs (e.g. PyCharm) show this as a potential error, because they cannot statically infer what my metaclass is doing.
Is there a way to annotate somehow `inc` in order to make the warning disappear?

I tried using a stub file, but this didn't help:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def inc(x): ...

# also this
class A:
    inc: staticmethod
```

My final goal is to make PyCharm understand that the method is already static. Is this even possible with current versions of Python?